# Integral involving Bessel function, exponential, and power

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

In the course of a derivation I encountered the following integral and was unable to find it in standard integral tables (though I found one that looked very similar).

Here, $\beta$ is a positive real number.
$$
\int_{0}^{a} \frac{1-e^{-\beta x}}{x}J_0(x) dx
$$
Is there a known formula for this integral, or if not, for when the upper integral bound approaches infinity?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use the same letter for the variable of integration and an endpoint of the interval.

Comment: Neither Maple nor Wolfram Alpha come up with a closed form, either for an antiderivative or the definite integral from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I've tried Wolfram Alpha previously. Any idea where else I can look in the literature for integrals of this kind?

Comment: If you incorporate $\beta>0$ as an assumption, then Mathematica actually does give a simple closed form for the $a=\infty$ case. More precisely, `Integrate[(1-Exp[-b x])/x *BesselJ[0,x],{x,0,Infinity},Assumptions->b>0]`  yields $\sinh^{-1}\beta$ as the result.

Comment: @Semiclassical, very interesting! Thanks for sharing this. Do you know if this is reciprocal $\sinh$ or $\operatorname{arcsinh}$?

Comment: Arcsinh. See the answer below.

Comment: Infinty series: $$\int_0^a \frac{\left(1-e^{-x \beta }\right) J_0(x)}{x} \, dx=-\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-a \beta )^j \,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{j}{2};1,1+\frac{j}{2};-\frac{a^2}{4}\right)}{j^2 \Gamma (j)}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To substantiate the partial answer provided by Mathematica in comments above, the following integral is known to be valid when $\beta'\geq 0$: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta' x} J_0(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\beta'^2}}$$
(This is usually found in a table of Laplace transforms.) Integrating from $\beta'=0$ to $\beta$ then yields

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-\beta x}}{x}J_0(x)\,dx=\int_0^\beta \frac{d\beta'}{\sqrt{1+\beta'^2}}=\sinh^{-1}\beta=\operatorname{arcsinh} \beta$$ using a standard integral representation of arcsinh. (A more scrupulous calculation would check that this integration is legitimate, but since the integrand vanishes exponentially fast as $x\to\infty$ I'm not especially concerned.)

Comment: Thank you for the informative reply! Is there hope that a closed form expression might be obtained for the finite a case?

Comment: If there is one it's not at all evident. The easiest way to prove the first identity is to expand $J_0(x)$ in powers of $x$ and integrate term-by-term. But if $a<\infty$, then the resulting terms include polynomial dependence on $a\beta'$ which makes resumming altogether unlikely. The resulting series expansion may nevertheless be useful so I'll consider adding it.

Comment: I see, thanks so much for your answer!